# Reagarding the app deployment in tomcat 7

Tags: web-applications, tomcat7

I have created app , I want to deploy the same in tomcat server, earler same was getting deployed in resin web server. I have copied the same app and place it in the webpapps folder of tomcat.

```
But when I hit the URL apachehome:port/appname , in logs I am getting "Get /appname HTTP/1.1" 404 514
```

Comment: check whether you see tomcat page when you hit http://localhost:8080/

Comment: YEs , I can see the tomcat home page.

Answer (score 0):

After placing your app in the `webapp` folder of `Tomcat`. Restart the `Tomcat`.